# Check occurrence of keyword with value in sublist

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, plist

I have a data structure, consisting of property lists within lists, which are themselves inside a list. Essentially a 2d matrix of plists. It's of the form:

```
(((:VALUE 0 :GROUP 0) (:VALUE 0 :GROUP 0))
 ((:VALUE 0 :GROUP 0) (:VALUE 0 :GROUP 0))
 ((:VALUE 0 :GROUP 0) (:VALUE 0 :GROUP 0)))
```

Each :value and :group will contain an arbitrary integer value. I need to find if any of the :group keywords are 0. I've been trying to achieve this with the `member` function, but it only ever returns `nil`.

My code, assuming the data structure is called `data`, is:

```
(member '(:group 0) data :test 'equal))
```

How would I use the `member` function to check the occurrence of `:group 0` in a sublist of a sublist? (if indeed that's possible, or should I just use a couple of loops to iterate through?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`getf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm) as
the [`:key`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35074595/850781)
for [`find`/`find-if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_.htm)
and/or [`remove`/`remove-if-not`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm):

## Level 1 nesting

#### Prepare the data

```
(defparameter *data-1*
  (loop repeat 10 collect (list :value (random 10) :group (random 10))))
*data-1*
((:VALUE 7 :GROUP 4) (:VALUE 9 :GROUP 6) (:VALUE 2 :GROUP 7) (:VALUE 8 :GROUP 2)
 (:VALUE 5 :GROUP 6) (:VALUE 4 :GROUP 7) (:VALUE 3 :GROUP 5) (:VALUE 8 :GROUP 7)
 (:VALUE 0 :GROUP 3) (:VALUE 5 :GROUP 5))
```

#### A: Find the **1st** occurrence of group 7:

```
(find 7 *data-1* :key (lambda (pl) (getf pl :group)))
==> (:VALUE 2 :GROUP 7)
```

#### B: Find **all** occurrences of group 7:

```
(remove 7 *data-1* :key (lambda (pl) (getf pl :group)) :test-not #'eql)
==> ((:VALUE 2 :GROUP 7) (:VALUE 4 :GROUP 7) (:VALUE 8 :GROUP 7))
```

## Level 2 nesting

#### Prepare the data:

```
(defparameter *data-2*
  (loop repeat 10 collect
      (loop repeat (random 4) collect
          (list :value (random 10) :group (random 10)))))
*data-2*
(((:VALUE 9 :GROUP 9) (:VALUE 8 :GROUP 2) (:VALUE 6 :GROUP 7)) NIL
 ((:VALUE 9 :GROUP 5)) ((:VALUE 9 :GROUP 1)) NIL
 ((:VALUE 2 :GROUP 7) (:VALUE 6 :GROUP 5) (:VALUE 2 :GROUP 1))
 ((:VALUE 1 :GROUP 4) (:VALUE 5 :GROUP 5))
 ((:VALUE 9 :GROUP 7) (:VALUE 9 :GROUP 8) (:VALUE 7 :GROUP 4))
 ((:VALUE 4 :GROUP 7)) NIL)
```

#### C: Find the **1st** occurrence of group 7:

```
(find-if (lambda (l)
           (find 7 l :key (lambda (pl) (getf pl :group))))
         *data-2*)
==> ((:VALUE 9 :GROUP 9) (:VALUE 8 :GROUP 2) (:VALUE 6 :GROUP 7))
```

#### D: Find **all** occurrences of group 7:

```
(remove-if-not (lambda (l)
                 (find 7 l :key (lambda (pl) (getf pl :group))))
               *data-2*)
==>
(((:VALUE 9 :GROUP 9) (:VALUE 8 :GROUP 2) (:VALUE 6 :GROUP 7))
 ((:VALUE 2 :GROUP 7) (:VALUE 6 :GROUP 5) (:VALUE 2 :GROUP 1))
 ((:VALUE 9 :GROUP 7) (:VALUE 9 :GROUP 8) (:VALUE 7 :GROUP 4))
 ((:VALUE 4 :GROUP 7)))
```

## Define functions:

Depending on your needs, you might want to define functions

```
(defun get-group (plist)
  (getf plist :group))
(defun find-group (list-of-plists group)
  (find group list-of-plists :key #'get-group))
(defun make-group-finder (group)
  (lambda (list-of-plists) (find-group list-of-plists group)))
```

Now you can use them for the tasks above:

**A:**  `(find-group *data-1* 7)`

**B:**  `(remove 7 *data-1* :key #'get-group :test-not #'eql)`

**C:**  `(find-if (make-group-finder 7) *data-2*)`

**D:**  `(remove-if-not (make-group-finder 7) *data-2*)`

**PS** [`remove-if-not`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) is the Lisp idiom for "filter".

Comment: Unfortunately `(find 7 data :key (lambda (pl) (getf pl :group)))` still returned `nil`. I tested `(getf data :group)` and that was returning `nil`. May I point out that your generated data structure isn't quite the same as mine, as it is only a list of plists, not a list of lists of plists.