# Common lisp identity-groups

Tags: grouping, common-lisp

I am a lisp beginner and i wrote a function to group `equal` adjacent items in a list. I would be grateful if Lisp experts could give me some advice about a better lispy writing of this function. Thanks in advance!

```
(defun identity-groups (lst)
  (labels ((travel (tail group groups)
         (cond ((endp tail) (cons group groups))
           ((equal (car tail) (car (last group)))
            (travel (cdr tail) (cons (car tail) group) groups))
           (t (travel (cdr tail) (list (car tail)) (cons group groups))))))
    (reverse (travel (cdr lst) (list (car lst)) nil))))

(identity-groups '(1 3 5 4 4 4 4 5 1 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7))
;; => ((1) (3) (5) (4 4 4 4) (5) (1) (2 2 2) (1) (2) (3 3 3 3 3) (4) (5) (6) (7))
```

Comment: Based on your description, I would expect `(identity-groups '(1 3 5 4 5 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))` to return `((7) (6) (2 2) (4 4) (5 5 5) (3 3) (1 1 1))`  (with maybe a different order for groups), but your function currently does not return that, but a list of singletons: `((1) (3) (5) (4) (5) (1) (2) (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7))`. Is that expected?

Comment: Sorry, it should group only adjacent equal items. Edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks pretty good!

- `(equal (car tail) (car (last group)))` seems equivalent to `(equal (car tail) (car group))`
- To keep the elements in the original order, reverse the items of every group.
- As you build the resulting list `groups` yourself, it's safe and more efficient to use `nreverse` instead of `reverse`.
- There is no name clash when using `list` as parameter, instead of `lst`, as variables and functions live in different namespaces ("Lisp-2").
- It's considered good style to give utility functions like this `&key test key` arguments so callers can decide on when list elements are considered equal (see e.g. [Common lisp :KEY parameter use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074595/common-lisp-key-parameter-use)), to join the club of general functions like `member`, `find` and `sort`.
- And a documentation string! :)

Updated version:

```
(defun identity-groups (list &key (test #'eql) (key #'identity))
  "Collect adjacent items in LIST that are the same. Returns a list of lists."
  (labels ((travel (tail group groups)
             (cond ((endp tail) (mapcar #'nreverse (cons group groups)))
                   ((funcall test
                             (funcall key (car tail))
                             (funcall key (car group)))
                    (travel (cdr tail) (cons (car tail) group) groups))
                   (t (travel (cdr tail) (list (car tail)) (cons group groups))))))
    (nreverse (travel (cdr list) (list (car list)) nil))))
```

Tests:

```
(identity-groups '(1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 3 2 2 1))
-> ((1) (2 2 2) (3 3 3) (4) (3) (2 2) (1))

;; Collect numbers in groups of even and odd:
(identity-groups '(1 3 4 6 8 9 11 13 14 15) :key #'oddp)
-> ((1 3) (4 6 8) (9 11 13) (14) (15))

;; Collect items that are EQ:
(identity-groups (list 1 1 2 2 (list "A") (list "A")) :test 'eq)
-> ((1 1) (2 2) (("A")) (("A")))
```

Comment: Some questions about reversing: first i dont understand what `(mapcar #'nreverse (cons group groups))` does on each group, since the group items are all the same. Second question: is it not cheaper to `nreverse` the output of `travel`  once at the end , instead of `nrevers`ing groups on every recursion? Also the `:test` function will always be comparing boolean values? `(identity-groups (list 1 1 2 2 (list "A") (list "A")) :test 'EQUALITY)` will return the same groupings for `eq, eql, equal`.

Comment: 1: remove the `(mapcar #'nreverse)` and check the output of the `oddp` example (this is done once at the end, not on every recursion).
2: I don't think that will work; also see 1.
3: `(eq (list "A") (list "A"))` and `(equal ..)`differ.

Answer (score 3):

The desired function fits the pattern which consists in building a value `G1` from a known subresult `G0` and a new value, and can be implemented using [`REDUCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm).

The first parameter of the anonymous reducing function is the accumulator, here a list of groups. The second parameter is the new value.

```
(reduce (lambda (groups value)
           (let ((most-recent-group (first groups)))
              (if (equal (first most-recent-group) value)
                  (list* (cons value most-recent-group) (rest groups))
                  (list* (list value) groups))))
        '(1 3 5 4 4 4 4 5 1 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7)
        :initial-value ())
```

The result is:

```
((7) (6) (5) (4) (3 3 3 3 3) (2) (1) (2 2 2) (1) (5) (4 4 4 4) (5) (3) (1))
```

One problem in your code is the call to `last` to access the last group, which makes the code traverse lists again and again. Generally you should avoid treating lists as arrays, but use them as stacks (only manipualte the top elment).

If you need to reverse elements, you can use do it at the end of each group (order among equivalent values), or at the end of the whole function (order among groups).

Answer (score 1):

**A 'classical' recursive solution**

```
(defun identity-groups (l &key (test #'eql))
  (labels ((group (l last-group acc)
              (cond ((null l) (cons last-group acc))
                    ((and last-group (funcall test (car l) (car last-group)))
                     (group (cdr l) (cons (car l) last-group) acc))
                    (t
                     (group (cdr l) (list (car l)) (cons last-group acc))))))
    (cdr (reverse (group l '() '())))))
```

**Older version** (requires an initial-value not equal to first list element)

So the version above got rid of this key argument.

```
(defun identity-groups (l &key (test #'eql) (initial-value '(0))) 
  (labels ((group (l last-group acc)
              (cond ((null l) (cons last-group acc))
                    ((funcall test (car l) (car last-group))
                     (group (cdr l) (cons (car l) last-group) acc))
                    (t
                     (group (cdr l) (list (car l)) (cons last-group acc))))))
    (cdr (reverse (group l initial-value '())))))
```

**Imperative-style looping construct**

Tried for fun also a looping construct with `do`.

```
(defun group-identicals (l &key (test #'eql))
  (let ((lx) (tmp) (res))                       ;; initiate variables
    (dolist (x l (reverse (cons tmp res)))      ;; var list return/result-value
      (cond ((or (null lx) (funcall test x lx)) ;; if first round or 
             (push x tmp)            ;; if last x (lx) equal to current `x`,
             (setf lx x))          ;; collect it in tmp and set lx to x
            (t (push tmp res)      ;; if x not equal to lastx, push tmp to result
               (setf tmp (list x)) ;; and begin new tmp list with x
               (setf lx x))))))    ;; and set last x value to current x
    (cdr (reverse (group l initial-value '()))))) 
    ;; cdr removes initial last-group value

;; test:
(group-identicals '(1 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 3 3 3 3))
;; ((1) (2) (3 3) (4 4 4 4) (5 5) (6) (3 3 3 3))
(group-identicals '("a" "b" "b" "c" "d" "d" "d" "e") :test #'string=)
;; (("a") ("b" "b") ("c") ("d" "d" "d") ("e"))
```

Comment: `(identity-groups '(0 0 0 0)) => NIL`. So this way one should always set an `:initial-value` to get correct groups, right?

Comment: @atymuri, the :initial-value must be different than first element, like `(identity-groups '(0 0 0 0 0) :initial-value '(1))` -> `((0 0 0 0 0))` but `(identity-groups '(0 0 0 0 0) :initial-value '(0))` -> NIL

Comment: @ateymuri: now the first solution got rid of `:initial-value`.